# Uso da vírgula - "por que a Argentina consegue e o Brasil, não?"

Tags: gramática, vírgula, figuras-de-linguagem

Vi a seguinte chamada no UOL hoje:

**"Tales Torraga: 2ª final em três Copas; por que a Argentina consegue e o Brasil, não?"**

Sobre a vírgula antes do "não", o uso está correto?
Se continuássemos a frase, teríamos: "por que a Argentina consegue e o Brasil não consegue?". Daí, teríamos uma separação de sujeito de verbo com vírgula (sem aposto), o que é errado.
Qual seria a regra para o uso da vírgula no caso acima?

Comment: só para deixar anotado, o UOL atualizou o texto original e removeu a vírgula. Vejam: https://www.uol.com.br/esporte/futebol/copa-do-mundo/2022/12/15/segunda-final-em-tres-copas-por-que-a-argentina-consegue-e-o-brasil-nao.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse me parece um caso de **zeugma**: omissão de um termo para evitar repetição, omissão essa que é quase sempre marcada pela vírgula. Na frase em questão, "consegue" é omitido.

Um exemplo popular da zeugma é a letra de Chico Buarque:

> O meu pai era paulista / Meu avô, pernambucano / O meu bisavô, mineiro / Meu tataravô, baiano

em que o verbo "ser" é reiteradamente omitido, após estar presente na primeira frase.

Penso que a frase

> Por que a Argentina consegue e o Brasil, não?

não usa a construção mais canônica de zeugma, mas pode ser considerada correta como está, até por se tratar de uma chamada que, como títulos e manchetes, tem estilo próprio, mas também porque as regras em relação ao zeugma parecem terem evoluído rapidamente no sentido de menor rigidez.

Por exemplo, ao final do último milênio Pasquale [defendia](https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/fsp/cotidian/ff2511199909.htm) a obrigatoriedade do ponto e vírgula ou do ponto final separando as orações:

> Um aspecto sobre o qual não há discordância e que merece ser citado é o do ponto-e-vírgula que separa as orações, considerado obrigatório quando se emprega a vírgula que marca a elipse do verbo: "Sou gremista; eles, colorados"; "Nós preferimos cinema; eles, teatro". No lugar do ponto-e-vírgula, também se pode usar o ponto final: "Eu trabalho com fatos. Você, com hipóteses".

E, embora essa continue sendo a construção preponderante, não é exclusiva. Por exemplo, a [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma) contém um exemplo com vírgula:

> Ela anda de bicicleta, ele de moto.

e Érico Veríssimo [opta](https://books.google.de/books?id=yX5_DwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT15&ots=7l5xL5fQc7&dq=%E2%80%9CA%20vida%20%C3%A9%20um%20grande%20jogo%20e%20o%20destino%2C%20um%20parceiro%20tem%C3%ADvel.%E2%80%9D%20(%C3%89rico%20Ver%C3%ADssimo)&pg=PT16#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9CA%20vida%20%C3%A9%20um%20grande%20jogo%20e%20o%20destino,%20um%20parceiro%20tem%C3%ADvel.%E2%80%9D%20(%C3%89rico%20Ver%C3%ADssimo)&f=false) pela conjunção "e" apenas:

> “A vida é um grande jogo e o destino, um parceiro temível.”

E há também até mesmo exemplos em que a vírgula que marca a zeugma é omitida — como o da Wikipédia, acima, e também ([1](https://www.normaculta.com.br/zeugma/), [2](https://www.portugues.com.br/gramatica/zeugma.html)):

> Eu comi musse de manga; ele de chocolate.
> Diante dela, estavam os pais e os irmãos. E também os tios e os avós.

Embora me pareça preferível manter esta vírgula, talvez com exceção do último exemplo acima, em que a segunda oração parece apenas continuar a listagem com que a primeira termina.

Assim, voltando à frase da pergunta original, provavelmente uma construção mais canônica seria: "Por que a Argentina consegue; e o Brasil, não?" mas a opção por não usar o ponto e vírgula se justifica, não apenas por ser uma chamada (naturalmente mais simples), mas também porque o cerne da pergunta é "por que não o Brasil?", enquanto a separação por vírgula poderia sugerir duas perguntas (esta e também "por que a Argentina?").

---

Vale observar, sobre a definição de zeugma: algumas fontes, especialmente mais recentes, consideram a zeugma um caso particular de "elipse" (omissão), enquanto outras, mais antigas, consideram que a zeugma é distinta da elipse, pois a omissão seria parcial, já que apenas evita a repetição de um termo presente.

Comment: Eu cá encontro problema grande com a frase, não porque a vírgula opcional da zeugma me soe em falta, mas sim porque a vírgula final parte a frase de uma forma que me é dissonante. "Não porque me falte a vírgula mas sim por, ser dissonante." - só me faria sentido como uma figura de estilo sonora, uma maneira de indicar procura de uma parte final que escapasse, ou de causar impacto artificial indicando uma certa estranheza do orador à conclusão que ele próprio apresenta.

Comment: Entendo seu ponto, @ANeves mas essa vírgula que te causa estranheza **é** a vírgula da zeugma. O que "falta" nessa frase é o ponto e vírgula ou vírgula antes de "e". Você não estranha também a vírgula no consagrado "meu bisavô, mineiro"?

Answer (score 2):

No Brasil, costumamos denominar essa vírgula 'elipse do verbo'. "João foi ao cinema; Maria, não". A vírgula marca a omissão [elipse] do verbo [no caso, foi]. Note que há paralelismo dos tempos verbais [foi-foi]; no entanto, já vi falta de consenso entre especialistas sobre  se essa vírgula poderia ser usada na frase "João foi ao cinema; seus irmãos, não" [foi-foram]. Espero ter ajudado.